# How to pass URL path to inputStream

Tags: java

```
public void insertImage(HSSFWorkbook workbook,HSSFSheet sheet){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("\\img\\logo.png");
            byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            int pictureureIdx = workbook.addPicture(imageBytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
            inputStream.close();
            CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
            Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
            anchor.setCol1(0);
            anchor.setRow1(0);
            Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(an`enter code here`chor, pictureureIdx);
            pict.resize(0.4);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

This is my java code for inserting logo image in excel file.I want to pass path from URL like "http://localhost:8080/Enertech/img/logo.png"
How to rewrite the above code.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try getting a stream from the URL ?. Just try changing that one line and check.

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Enertech/img/logo.png").openStream();
```